# Making JSHint recognize TestComplete's USEUNIT directive

Tags: javascript, jshint, testcomplete

I'm attempting to use JSHint to improve code quality here, and I've run into a slight issue.  TestComplete provides us with a comment "directive", //USEUNIT, which allows us to reference another file in our test scripts.  It works like this:

FileA.sj:

```
function foo()
{
  // do stuff
}
```

FileB.sj

```
//USEUNIT FileA
function main()
{
  FileA.foo();
}
```

Now, TestComplete doesn't *require* us to qualify the function name with the source unit, but we have defined it in our coding standards that we want this done.  I'm trying to figure out where to modify JSHint to allow for the //USEUNIT command/directive, and make it recognize that //USEUNIT defined an object that should be treated as a new valid keyword.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I have already figured out how to extend JSHint to recognize the default TestComplete objects, so that's not the issue.  I'm trying to figure out how to get it to recognize the USEUNIT.